# Парсинг строки в Java

Tags: android, строки, java, синтаксический-анализ

Привет.

Задача такая: есть строка - "12*3-4+342/2.54".

Нужно спарсить последнее число после знака, т.е. 2.54, причём вместо "/" может быть и "+" и "-" и "*". Подскажите, если несложно. Пытался вот так:

```
function getLastNumber() {
   if (lastSymbol == (0 || 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9 || .)) {
       lastNumber += lastSymbol;
       inverse(lastNumber);
   }
   getLastNumber()
}
```

Но оно не работает, выбрасывает из приложения при вызове функции. Видимо, что-то не так с рекурсией. Заранее извиняюсь за псевдокод... (:

Comment: ну и способ....  почитай про обратную польскую запись - ею решают такие задачи

Comment: ОПЗ решает немного другие задачи, и мне не нужно разбивать пример, мне просто нужно последнее число, и писать целый алгоритм ради этого как-то не правильно мне кажется.

Comment: ну если тебе надо последнии 4 знака - можно функцией взять их

Comment: Если уверены, что там число, то почему бы просто в цикле не двигаться посимвольно с конца строки пока символ цифра или точка? 

А потом прочесть число.

Comment: Вот когда появляется метка android у вопроса в котором ничего связано с андроидом, можно сразу понять, что решили перепрыгнуть через изучение java. "псевдокод" вообще жесть, и это вы говорили про костыли юзеру @Barmaley

Comment: Про андроид я упомянул лишь для того, чтобы если кто-то решит дать вариант решения на Java, то он не обязательно заведётся под андроидом. Хотя даже такое решение мне было бы полезно.

Comment: @avp, сделал как вы подсказали.
работал даже псевдокод, проблема была совсем в другом.
вопрос можно закрывать :)

Comment: @NeoTvidoz расскажите про обработку строки которая не заведется под андроидом? тем более такая тривиальная задача

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обобщенный алгоритм решения такой задачи это (не углубляясь в детали синтаксического анализа, польскую инверсную запись и проч.) это:

1. Разбивка выражения на токены. Под токеном мы понимаем в данном контексте разбивку на лексемы, то есть где символы, где числа, где операции. В данном случае:

   12*3-4+342/2.54

   получается 9 токенов: `{'12', '*', '3', '-', '4', '+', '342', '/', '2.54'}`
2. Далее парсирование токенов - мы определяем кто есть who, где операция, где символ, где переменная, а где константа
3. В зависимости от заданной грамматики выстраивание дерева решения (в частном случае польская инверсная запись) - на выходе будет что-то типа: `{'342', '2.54', '/', '12', '3', '*', '4', '-', '+'}`
4. Засовываем дерево в решатель

Применительно к вопросу: на этапе 2 вы получите свой `2.54` легко и непринужденно.

Answer (score 0):

Немного быдловато)) Но можно и через регулярку

```
 StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer("12*3-4+342/2.54", "+-*");
    String result="";
    while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
            result = tokenizer.nextToken();
    }
    return result;
```

Comment: Не надо использовать StringTokenizer, StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "12*3-4+342/2.54";
String[] arr = str.split("(\\*|-|\\+|/)");
```

вот, вообщем-то, и все...

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как сильно нормальная java отличается от андройдовской, но тут напрашиваются регулярные выражения

```
        String s= "12*3-4+342/2.54";
        Pattern pattern= Pattern.compile("(/|\\*|\\+|-)([\\d.]*)$");
        Matcher m=pattern.matcher(s);
        if(m.find()){
            System.out.println(m.group(2));
        }
```