# Работа с математическими выражениями переданные в виде аргументов типа String

Tags: java, строки

```
int k = 8*50+50;
```

не выдает ошибку.

Ну интуитивно понятно, почему результат 450, но при

```
String s = "8*50+50";
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(s));
```

будет выдано ошибка, и это понятно.

У меня есть цель написать программу, в котором неважно какое математическое выражение написано в виде String, программа берет и делает то же самое, что и во время

int k = 8*50+50;

Я конечно нашел один полезный код в англоязычной стаковерфлоу, вот

```
String str = "qwerty15qwerty2";
        str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str.trim().split(" ")));
```

но тут использовано регулярное выражение, а было бы намного полезнее, увидеть как можно в строке распознать числа разных размеров, будь это 10, или 100 и тд.. через циклы, массивы и/или контейнеры.

Но это для выше найденного куска кода я сказал, а насчет моего вопроса:

Не только надо найти в строке разные числа но и обратить внимание на +,-,/,* чтобы автоматический провести правильный подсчет.

Пока через циклы, массивы что не делаю, не получается получить желаемый результат, поэтому решил во всяком случае поделится тут с данной ситуацией. Даже если не полноценный ответ, то хотя бы полезную подсказку получить.

Comment: то, что вы описываете, звучит как парсинг математического выражения. Для этого есть разные подходы. В простых случаях можно распарить выражение вручную, регулярками или используя преобразование из инфиксной нотации в обратную польскую и вычислить вырежение с помощью стеков. В сложных случаях вам придется строить абстрактное синтаксическое дерево и производить вычисления на нем (например, если цель не вычислить, а упростить выражение). Но это если вы сами это хотите реализовать, а не просто найти [готовую библиотеку](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4682096/312041) для такого.

Comment: @tym32167 Пусть будет готовая библиотека специально предназначенная для решения выше задачи, главное чтобы было можно посмотреть код,пошаговый алгоритм, через которого решается данная проблема. Иначе к примеру с регулярками, вроде все более гладко и короче, но как то по халтурский получается, в смысле вроде что то близкое к твоей нужде нашел, а как сам получить такой результат но без готового чужого кода(конечно же, не изучая сокрытую реализацию этого чужого кода) - даже прозрачно представить не можешь.

Comment: так я ж вам и скинул ссылку, вы её смотрели?

Comment: @tym32167 Благодарю, ссылка на библиотеку полезная и решает львиную долю моей задачи (на практике попробовал), а вот насколько остаточная проблема, пока точно не могу оценить, нужно время.

Comment: что значит `остаточная проблема`? Используя код по ссылке вы легко решите все ваши примеры из вопроса.

Comment: кстати, вот одно настораживает... что означает  Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release ??? во время проверки библиотеки выдало. у меня 12-ая версия java если что

Comment: имею ввиду, данный warning угрожает, что в будущем эту возможность библиотеки не удастся использовать?

Comment: Видимо, да, [будут выпиливать](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/335), но про альтернативы не пишут. Но если вы поглядите по ссылке ещё раз, там есть и другие достойные ответы.

Comment: Ну тогда  я рад, что успел узнать про эту библиотеку, до того как некоторые его возможности выпилят. Спасибо вам за поддержку.

Comment: недавно отвечал на вопрос про парсинг математического выражения. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1040990/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5/1041020#1041020

Comment: @Дмитрий Спасибо за инфо, думаю это именно тот ответ, который я ожидал.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Парсинг строки в Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/164366/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-java)